# Why is my superuser username suddenly user2293 instead of leeand00?

Tags: support, username

Must be a bug or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a bug.

Due to the change to global logins and to make the functionality of the @ reply system more effective, the OpenID username is no longer inferred as it was in the past. You now have to set your username or the system will generate a random one.

More on this topic at Meta Stack Overflow [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65006/why-are-you-no-longer-inferring-user-names-from-openid)

Comment: Okay I changed my username, and that seems to have fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, was already wondering why this happened.