# Why did my nickname change

Tags: support, username

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my superuser username suddenly user2293 instead of leeand00?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1658/why-is-my-superuser-username-suddenly-user2293-instead-of-leeand00)

Why has my nickname changed on a few sites in the StackOverflow network, and how can I change them back ?

Sorry if this is the wrong location to ask this but as Superuser is one of them.

Comment: Well I found were to change it but I wonder how it ended up as userXXXX while it was Xeross before

Comment: Because you didn't set a name in the first place

Comment: Weird as I recall that it has always been Xeross on all sites and one day I logged in and saw it was changed :/

Comment: Please read the answer in the duplicate, it explains why it used to work and why it changed.